# How to copy text form multiple fragments using Clipboard

Tags: android, android-fragments, copy, clipboard

I have implemented same fragment multiple times in single activity. Now I want to copy text from all the fragments but I am getting text only from 1st fragment. How I can append text in clipboard from multiple fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to append text to clipboard:

```
fun copyToClipBoards(content: String,context : Context) {

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        val clipboard = context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as android.text.ClipboardManager
        val text=clipboard.text.toString()
        clipboard.text = text.plus(content)
    } else {
        val clipboard = context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as android.content.ClipboardManager
        val text=clipboard.primaryClip.getItemAt(0).text.toString()
        val clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", text.plus(content))
        clipboard.primaryClip = clip
    }

}
```

Hope it will helps!!